# How long does URL from ImagesService.getServingUrl last

Tags: java, google-app-engine, image-processing, blobstore

I'm working with the blobstore and imagesService in App Engine.  I'm wondering how long a URL I get from imagesService.getServingUrl(blobKey) will last.  If I'm using this to store a users profile picture, can I store this URL in the user or should I store the BlobKey and get the servingUrl each time i need the picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL will last indefinitely. You should definitely still store the blobkey anyway, though, or you will have no way to delete blobs once you no longer need them, or to get alternate image serving URLs.

Comment: awesome, I store the blobkey just didn't want to call this each time.  What would be a reason for alternate URLs?

Comment: The get_serving_url lets you specify the dimensions you want the image resized to, and other parameters you may want to vary.