# App Engine Image Service Link Stopped Working (HTTP 404)

Tags: google-app-engine

We are storing images in Google Cloud Storage.  We've generated a link, using the image service getServingUrl().  This link worked for some amount of time (a few hours) and then stopped working.  We've got reports that the link is still accessible in the US, but not the UK.

Here's the link: http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HkwzeUinidFxi-z6OO4ANasEuVYZYduhMiPG2SraKstC5Val0xGdTqvePNMr_bs7FLvj1oNzZjSWZe4dKcugaZ5hzaqfWlw=s36

Is anybody else experiencing this problem at all?  If yes, has anyone cut them a ticket to investigate?

Comment: I confirm that the image can be seen in the U.S. Also, when I tell my browser to emulate London coordinates, the image shows up as well.

Comment: use PHP instead of java you can refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646849/how-can-we-use-firebase-image-file-and-resize-them-using-get-serving-url/37673504#37673504

Answer (score 0):

This is a known behavior for years. The `getServingUrl()` generates a temporary link to a CDN that is not guaranteed to last forever.

You have to generate a link on every request or from time to time or to use other solutions.

We ended up moving our images to S3 + CloudFront from Amazon. You can consider https://cloud.google.com/storage/ & https://cloud.google.com/cdn/

Comment: Thanks for that info Alexander.  Still feels like something has changed/broken recently however - we've been relying on those links being stable for months at a time for a few years now I believe.

Comment: May be it was stable for a while after we moved out. We've started when the AppEngine was in it's infancy and there were a lot of downtime at data-center level. My understanding (guess) the serving URL reference where it is stored - a data center ID (and maybe even a machine id) encoded in it so if there is an issue with data center or a rack or a server it simply can't be served. If you need reliability you have to use something that replicates data.

Comment: Thanks again for your thoughts Alexander.  I assumed that Google Cloud Storage provides the redundant, replicated storage and that the image service generates the URL and stores meta-data with it pointing at the correct place in Google Cloud Storage.  I'm guessing the data gets sucked into the CDN and on cache miss i.e. it's been evicted it would reload using the meta-data again.

Comment: Like yourself, I'm completely guessing however.  I don't see anything in Google's docs explaining that the link will expire however and this other thread seems to indicate that it won't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643892/how-long-does-url-from-imagesservice-getservingurl-last

Comment: I think you right, but it did not worked for us and seems is not working for you. Please update the thread if you get any response from Google.

Answer (score 0):

The serving URLs do not expire.  I have a website with roughly 500k images that has been using the same image URLs for about 4 years now.  All image links are still functioning and were only generated once (not on every request)